# Preventing ModalPopupExtender from closing during/after PostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, postback, modalpopupextender

How do I prevent my asp:ModalPopupExtender from closing after or during a postback to the server??

Here is my code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Confirm popup Ok button
function OnOk() {
    $('#confirmPopup').hide();
    ClickSaveButton();      // does a postback
    ShowGridPopup();
}
```

**ASP.NET AJAX**

```
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender BehaviorID="confirmPopup" ID="confirmPopup" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="butConfirm" PopupControlID="ConfirmView" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        OnOkScript="OnOk();" OnCancelScript="OnCancel();"
        OkControlID="yesButton" CancelControlID="noButton">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

No matter if I call `ShowGridPopup()` before or after the postback method `ClickSaveButton()`, the popup still dissapears. How can I prevent this?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the `ShowGridPopup()` and `ClickSaveButton()`

```
function ShowGridPopup() {
    if (getID() == "Popup1") {
        ShowGridPopup1();
    } else if (getID() == "Popup2") {
        ShowGridPopup2();
    }
}

function ClickSaveButton() {
    var _id = $('a[id$="butSave"]').attr("ID");
    __doPostBack(_id.replace("_", "$"), '');
}
```

Comment: In `ClickSaveButton();`, do you perform a full postback or an asyncpostback? Also, the code of `ClickSaveButton` and `ShowGridPopup` would help to find the problem.

Comment: I added the code as an edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to by pass this, here is my solution: You have to create a new `HiddenField` controller from the server-side in ASP that will be used to store the ID of the `ModalPopupExtender` that you want to show after postback, it is set to null if there is no popup to be shown.

```
<!-- Grid Popup ID: to obtain the grid popup ID from server-side -->
<asp:HiddenField id="gridPopupID" runat="server" value="" />
```

Next, we need to set the ID to the `HiddenField` before we use the save event

```
// Confirm popup Ok button
function OnOk() {
    $('#confirmPopup').hide();                          // hides the current confirmation popup
    $("#<%= gridPopupID.ClientID %>").val(getID());     // set the ID to the hiddenField.
    ClickSaveButton();                                  // simulates the click of the save button
}
```

Now, in the code behind, all we need to do is check the value of the `HiddenField` text field and we can just do a `.Show()` on the correct popup accordingly.

```
Protected Sub OnSaveAssociation(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles butSaveAssociation.Click

' ommited code: save changes to back end

            ' determine which popup to show
            Dim _id As String = gridPopupID.Value
            Select Case _id
                Case "Popup1"
                    gridPopup1.Show()
                    gridPopupID.Value = Nothing
                Case "Popup2"
                    gridPopup2.Show()
                    gridPopupID.Value = Nothing
            End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use `UpdatePanel`, so the ModalPopupExtender won't be hidden after postback. See this example below :

**Aspx:**

```
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
    </asp:ScriptManager> 
    <div> 
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpOutterUpdatePanel" runat="server"> 
             <ContentTemplate> 

                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonShow" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" OnClick="ButtonShow_Click" />                 


                <input id="dummy" type="button" style="display: none" runat="server" /> 
                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" 
                        ID="mpeThePopup" 
                        TargetControlID="dummy" 
                        PopupControlID="pnlModalPopUpPanel" 
                        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"                        
                        DropShadow="true"/>
                 <asp:Panel ID="pnlModalPopUpPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup"> 
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpInnerUpdatePanel" runat="Server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
                        <ContentTemplate> 
                            Message
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonClose" runat="server" Text="Close Popup" OnClick="ButtonClose_Click" />                                                                  
                        </ContentTemplate>       
                    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                 </asp:Panel> 

            </ContentTemplate> 
        </asp:UpdatePanel> 
    </div> 
    </form> 
</body>
```

**Code behind :**

```
    protected void ButtonShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show ModalPopup               

        mpeThePopup.Show(); 
    }
    protected void ButtonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Hide ModalPopup

        mpeThePopup.Hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use, ModalPopupExtender1.Show() with update panel to avoid the whole page refresh. This has worked perfectly for me.